# Get type of Generics

Tags: java, generics, retrofit2, generic-programming, robospice

I need to get type of generic type.
I've already tried following

```
public abstract class RetrofitRequest<RESULT> extends SpiceRequest<Response<RESULT>> {

    public RetrofitRequest(){
        super(Response<RESULT>.class); //compile time error
    }

    @Override
    public final Response<RESULT> loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        WebService webService = RestFulWebService.getRestFulWebService();
        return doInBackground(webService);
    }

    protected abstract Response<RESULT> doInBackground(WebService webService) throws Exception;

}
```

any idea how to get this done? thanks in advance!!!

and `SpiceRequest` is something like this

```
public abstract class SpiceRequest<RESULT> implements Comparable<SpiceRequest<RESULT>> {

    public SpiceRequest(Class<RESULT> clazz) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Thanks!

-supunz

Comment: Type erasure.  You're not going to get it easily.  Why doesn't this work for you anyway?  What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: because it generates a compile time error in `super(Response<RESULT>.class);`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that...?

Comment: since i extends my class with `SpiceRequest<Response<RESULT>>`, it needs to pass type of generics to parent constructor..

Comment: Actually, you don't.  If your parent class is typed, and your child class is typed, then at compile time it should resolve correctly.  Perhaps you should include your parent class (and a child class) to better explain your question.

Comment: Edit your question with this information, please.

Comment: When you use a `Class` instance as a run-time type token ("RTTT") you generally have to pass it in from the caller of the constructor. As you discovered, a `Class<R>` where `R` is a type parameter (conventionally spelled with a single uppercase letter), won't work. You have to pull it from the type's `class` literal or an instance where the compiler can "see" the specific resolution of the type parameter. Once you do that, then you have the full power of runtime generics. (You can also play games with unchecked casts, but that isn't usually great.)

Comment: The issue is that .class cannot be used on something with a type so no `List<Foo>.class` but `List.class` is OK

Comment: Thanks RC!!! it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved myself with the help of [RC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180100/rc) comment

```
public abstract class RetrofitRequest<RESULT> extends SpiceRequest<Response<RESULT>> {

    protected RetrofitRequest(){
        super((Class<Response<RESULT>>) (Class<?>) Response.class);
    }

    @Override
    public final Response<RESULT> loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        WebService webService = RestFulWebService.getRestFulWebService();
        return doInBackground(webService);
    }

    @WorkerThread
    protected abstract Response<RESULT> doInBackground(WebService webService) throws Exception;

}
```

and https://coderanch.com/t/681438/java/Class-Type-List-java#3196253 just saved my day

Comment: It might not be a good idea to use raw types, but if you use them, you could extend `SpiceRequest<Response<RESULT>>` normally and just call `super((Class) Response.class)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mirror your parent controller in asking for a `Class<RESULT>`.

```
public RetrofitRequest(Class<RESULT> clazz){
    super(clazz);
}
```

The regrettable thing is now that you have to carry that all the way down the inheritance chain, but should you want to instantiate it, you'd need to provide the class too:

```
RetrofitRequest<String> impl = new RetrofitRequestImpl<String>(String.class);
```